# How to turn off animation effect like change activity slide effect

Tags: android

I am developing android application.

How to turn off animation effect like change activity slide effect.

For only my application.

Answer (score 6):

Just call overridePendingTransition(0,0) in your activity when onResume() and on onPause()

Comment: Thank you. but I cannot found PendingTransition() func.. or Transition() func.. please tell me func name..

Comment: Oh.. I found overridePendingTransition() func.. It worked.. thank you very much..